# Alter code to be reusable across objects?

Tags: trigger, after-trigger, apex-sharing, helper

I'm working on this https://medium.com/salesforce-zolo/build-your-own-teams-feature-for-custom-objects-in-salesforce-963ed3630f4 but trying to instead alter it into a single helper class that creates Share records for any custom object instead of just the single one as shown in that link. Here is my original trigger as well as triggerhelper class:

```
trigger StrategicOpportunityTeamMemberTrigger on Strategic_Opportunity_Team_Member__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {
    SOTeamMemberTriggerHandler handler = new SOTeamMemberTriggerHandler();
    if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) {
        handler.createShares(Trigger.new);
   }
}



public void createShares(List<Strategic_Opportunity_Team_Member__c> teamMembers) {
    List<Strategic_Opportunity__Share> sharesToInsert = new List<Strategic_Opportunity__Share>();
    Set<String> insertedParentAndUser = new Set<String>();
    
    for (Strategic_Opportunity_Team_Member__c tm : teamMembers) {
        String parentAndUser = String.valueOf(tm.Strategic_Opportunity__c) + String.valueOf(tm.User__c);
        //do not insert a READ record if something has already been inserted.
        if (insertedParentAndUser.contains(parentAndUser) && tm.Access_Level__c == 'Read') continue;
        sharesToInsert.add(new Strategic_Opportunity__Share(
            //ParentId, UserOrGroupId, AccessLevel, RowCause
            ParentId = tm.Strategic_Opportunity__c,
            UserOrGroupId = tm.User__c,
            AccessLevel = tm.Access_Level__c,
            RowCause = Schema.Strategic_Opportunity__Share.rowCause.Strategic_Opportunity_Team__c           
        ));
        insertedParentAndUser.add(parentAndUser);
    }
    
    insert sharesToInsert;
}
```

However, I modified this and created this new generic Helper class-

```
public class TeamSharingHelper {

public void createShares(Id parentId, Schema.SObjectType shareSObjectType, String shareReason, Map<Id, String> userIdToAccessLevel) {
    List<SObject> shareRecords = new List<SObject>();
    
    for (Id userId : userIdToAccessLevel.keySet() ) {
        SObject shareRecord = shareSObjectType.newSObject(null, true);
        shareRecord.put('ParentId', parentId);
        shareRecord.put('UserOrGroupId', userId); 
        shareRecord.put('AccessLevel', userIdToAccessLevel.get(userId));
        shareRecord.put('RowCause', shareReason); 
        
        shareRecords.add(shareRecord);
    }
    
    insert shareRecords;
  }
}
```

I'm confused on which variables should be inputted in this new helper class as well as how to call it from my TriggerHelper as I'm getting errors while saving it. Right now I have-

```
public class SOTeamMemberTriggerHandler {

Map<Id, String> userIdToAccessLevel = new Map<Id, String> {UserInfo.getUserId() => 'Read'};

    TeamSharingHelper handler = new TeamSharingHelper();
    handler.createShares(Strategic_Opportunity__c.Id, Schema.Strategic_Opportunity__Share.SObjectType, 
                                   Schema.Strategic_Opportunity__Share.rowCause.Strategic_Opportunity_Team__c, userIdToAccessLevel);

 
 }
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is taking these arguments

```
public void createShares(Id parentId, 
                         Schema.SObjectType shareSObjectType, 
                         String shareReason, 
                         Map<Id, String> userIdToAccessLevel) {
```

You are passing `Strategic_Opportunity__c.Id` which is a variable of type Schema.SobjectField

You probably want to pass as the first argument

```
tm.Strategic_Opportunity__c - which is of type `Id` (it is a lookup field to the parent object)
```

Comment: how/where would i define the `tm` variable tho?

Comment: Loop through trigger.ne  we to get sobjects